# custom text on recording red status bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

My app is marked as VoiP and Audio in the Info.plist, and so when there is any recording happening in the background, the red status bar appears with the text "Recording". I was wondering if this text could be modified. I searched everywhere but can't find in the docs which parameter is associated with that.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339078/red-banner-comes-and-disappear-suddenly-when-press-home-button-during-recording/13339194#comment18402371_13339194

is it same issue ?

Comment: not really...but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible...closing this question.