# Red audio recording status bar "flashes" while app in *foreground*

Tags: ios8, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

There are many questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878991/hide-red-recording-status-bar-in-ios-app-when-not-recording), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339078/red-banner-comes-and-disappear-suddenly-when-press-home-button-during-recording)) regarding the double height red audio recording status bar, but all of them reference flashes when the app resigns into the background. I'm getting a flash, I'm assuming from an `AVCaptureSession` setup, while the app is in foreground.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: I also have this problem in iOS 8.

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to remove the audio input from the `AVCaptureSession`

```
    [self.captureSession removeInput:audioIn];
```

in which the `audioIn` is the `AVCaptureDeviceInput`object, that is initialised in the init method.

**Explanation:**
You get a flash because of the transition. When you go from view A to view B, and the object was allocated in view A. You get a flash because when the view B is presented, and view A still hasn’t deallocated the object. So it is still being used on “background” by view A. It’s the same thing when you are on a call and open an app while you are on a call.

Comment: do you know what's causing it to flash though? Is it because i'm transitioning to another view while the inputs are being removed?  I'm definitely removing them, but maybe it's a new ios8 security feature?  The app is always in the foreground when it happens.

Comment: 100+ For your answer :-) The irritating red colour is no more. Thanks @bruno

Comment: removing audio input in viewWillDisappear fixed issue! Thanks @bruno