# AVAudioRecorder background recording, how to show time on the red bar?

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder

I'm creating an app which using the AVAudioRecorder to record voices, when it goes background, a red bar shown on system status bar. I want to show the recording elapsed time on it, like the voice memo. Is it possible, and how?

Thanks.

Comment: I have read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643837/custom-text-on-recording-red-status-bar, I don't know whether there is a difference between VoIP and AVAudioRecorder.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, but I can't find anything to back that up. Apple definitely doesn't provide any way to provide completely custom text, and I doubt they provide a way to enable the "elapsed time", either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible because that will use some private api only to apple.
The red bar is shown by iOS to indicate there is an app in the background using audio resource, set in UIBackgroundModes in your info.plist, mostly audio or voip.

Because it is shown by iOS you can not modify it.